# Event click isn't working properly

Tags: jquery

I need help because I don't know what I did wrong with this script if you could possibly help.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/51629774 - I am trying to click the ask a question button toward the bottom

The Button is -

```
<button type="button" class="js-btn-ask-question js-ask-btn-m btn-ask-question btn pull-right" id="WMItemAskAQuestBtn"> Ask a question </button>
```

Script

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 13: // Enter
        $('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn')[0].click();
        break;
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn').click();`?

Answer (score 0):

The '#' id selector just returns 1 element, not an array, since each element should have a unique id. Here's the revised code:

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 13: // Enter
        $('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn').click();
        break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea I tried that but it still doesn't work so that is why I figured maybe if I put [0].  When I press enter it doesn't work but when the script is enabled on the page if I try to manually click the button it does nothing.  If its disabled it opens up the text box?

Comment: Maybe try debugging with console.log($('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn')) and/or trying to replicate this first with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is:

```
$('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn')[0].click();
```

When you are using # ie Id selector, it will return only one html object or it will select only one html object. So there is no need to use [0] in it. Just use:

```
$('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn').click();
```

It will click the matching Id button in the document.

PS: The best way to deal with such thing is put an alert like:

```
alert($('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn').html()); or alert($('#WMItemAskAQuestBtn').val());|
```

to check if any matching html element is there or not.